# Excel: Totaling where value is X or Y

Tags: excel

I've got an excel spreadsheet where one of the values is X or Y. I want a function to add up the amounts column for all the Xs then the same for all the Ys. So in the example below, the calculation for all Xs would be 1080 and all Ys 1100.

- X/Y: Amount
- X      :  500
- Y  :  600
- X   : 580
- Y   : 500

I'd then like to be able to calculate the mean and median of that figure, so for the mean, take the total of the Xs (1080) and divide by the number of cells with X (2). I don't know how to do this bit either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest you use the Sumif-formula!

Comment: Check the function `sumif`.

Answer (score 0):

So lets assume you have the X and Y in Col A with the values in Col B.

We could use the following formula for the Sum of X:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4,"X",B1:B4)
```

We could use the following formula for the Sum of Y:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4,"Y",B1:B4)
```

As for the Mean we take the above formala and divide by countif like this:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4,"X",B1:B4)/COUNTIF(A1:A4,"X")
=SUMIF(A1:A4,"Y",B1:B4)/COUNTIF(A1:A4,"Y")
```